# How to apply mixins to the schema in Spring doc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have some API defined using Spring codegen, and the snippet for @ApiResponse is defined below:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Created successfully", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Money.class)))
```

The schema **Money. class** uses different serializers, deserializers, and mixins.

I am using the below Springdoc dependency to generate the docs automatically:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

This is doing the purpose, but the example schema and example value in **Swagger UI** for POST are incorrect. When I use the "try it out" functionality of Swagger, the POST request fails because the example body automatically created by Swagger does not use appropriate mixins, etc.

The problem is that it should apply the different mixins, serializers, and deserializers, which are already provided. I have used below ModelResolver bean to define the custom ObjectMapper, but still, it is not working:

```
@Bean
    public ModelResolver modelResolver(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = builder.build();
        
        return new ModelResolver(mapper);
    }
```

I tried the below also, and it seems to be working, but it is not a good approach to define each and everything like this:

```
static {
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(Money.class, MoneyMixin.class);
    }
```

**Spring Boot Version: 2.7.10**

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: isnt it because you did not add the mixin to your objectMapper? ie `mapper.addMixIn(Money.class, MoneyMixin.class);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder is autowired here and it contains all the required mixins, I debugged it and I can see those mixins.